# Trigger Event Handler when any TextBox's text has changed

Tags: c#, c, winforms, visual-studio-2012, event-handling

I'm building a message of a very different format that will be sent every time a person's account information is created or updated. I'm generating the message from many text boxes in a form from multiple tabs.

The plan would be to load all of the current information from an account into a new message every time an account is opened, and then change values for any text boxes that have changed.

It would be easy but time consuming to perform this individually for each text box.

Would this work?

```
person_last_name.TextChanged += new EventHandler(AllTextBoxes_TextChanged);
person_first_name.TextChanged += new EventHandler(AllTextBoxes_TextChanged);

private void AllTextBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If it does, how could you use the sender object parameter to detect which TextBox triggered the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this should work

you can use a switch statement if you want to do something different for all textbox

```
private void AllTextBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string triggered = (e as TextBox).Name;
    switch (triggered)
    { 
    case "name1":
        //somecode
    case "name2":
        //somecode
    //etc
    } 
}
```

Comment: If the form object has any other event handles for the same action (TextChanged), will they trigger as well?

Comment: yes normaly they should... you can try it by doubling the += eventhandler and adding a msgbox in there. Normaly you would get it to pop twice

Answer (score 2):

If your `Xmal` code be like:

```
<TextBox Name="person_last_name" TextChanged="AllTextBoxes_TextChanged"></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="person_first_name" TextChanged="AllTextBoxes_TextChanged"></TextBox>
```

You can detect triggered text-box like this:

```
 private void AllTextBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string triggered = (e as TextBox).Name;
            if (triggered == "yourtarget")
            {
                //Do some thing with selected
                //(e as TextBox).
            }
        }
```

Comment: But you could also do...

`person_last_name.TextChanged += new EventHandler(AllTextBoxes_TextChanged);`

... instead of editing the XAML, right?

Comment: just add a switch and check for name of textbox;) yes

Comment: @Glimpse:yes,you can do it like that